# SQL Replace with Aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

We are trying to replace the output of certain items in columns to shorten them (ie. Information Session to Info Session).  With our current SQL, the replace function doesn't seem to be allowing the statement to run within our environment.  Admittadly, I'm new to using the replace function and am not sure if it is being used in the correct way.  Please advise!

```
select [Date], [Time], [Event], [Students], [Guests]
from (
select
    e.[id],
    format(e.[date], 'h:mm tt') as [Time],
    e.[date],
    replace('Information Session','Information','Info') e.[summary] as [Event],
  (
    select count(*) 
    from [event.registration] 
    where [event] = e.[id] and [cancelled] is null
    ) as [Students],
  (
  select sum([guests]) 
  from [event.registration] 
  where [event] = e.[id] and [cancelled] is null
  ) as [Guests]
from [event] e
where e.[category] 
in ('Campus Visit', 'Information Session', 'Campus Tour', 'Athletics and    Wellness Tour') and format(e.[date], 'MM/dd/yyyy') = format(getdate(), 'MM/dd/yyyy')

) base
order by [Time] asc
```

Comment: well, what do you want to do, since `replace('Information Session','Information','Info') e.[summary]` doesn't explain at all what's your desired result

Comment: Right now the output would show "Information Session", we'd like to shorten it to "Info Session" to display

Comment: Then use `REPLACE(e.[Summary],'Information','Info')`

Answer (score 0):

The whole query looks a bit strange to me. For ewach row that you get back you do 2 extra querys towards the registration table, the count(*) and sum(guests).

THis might not be a problem but for big tables you would get performance issues and possible table locks.

I suggest tidying it up a bit like:

```
SELECT
    e.[date],
    FORMAT(e.[date], 'h:mm tt') AS [Time],
    REPLACE(e.[category],'Information','Info')  AS [Event],
    COUNT(er.id) as [Students],
    SUM(er.[guests])
FROM [event] e
LEFT JOIN [event.registration] er 
ON er.[event] = e.[id] AND [cancelled] IS NOT NULL
WHERE 
    e.[category] IN ('Campus Visit', 'Information Session', 'Campus Tour', 'Athletics and    Wellness Tour') 
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,e.[date], GETDATE())=0

ORDER BY [Time] ASC
```

I also replaced your WHERE format(e.[date], 'MM/dd/yyyy')... to a datediff for less operations in the query.

There might be some errors in this but since I don't have access to your table definitions it is hard to test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!